# Где в списке Python элемент не вписался в длину?

Tags: python, list, indexerror

У меня алгоритм, который должен, подчиняясь некоторому условию `if` с разностью, скинуть в пустой список `string_one_1` определенную строку (элемент) иного списка `string_all`.

Длина `string_all` составляет 10, длина `x_i_list` (переменная `num`) равна 11.

Сейчас получаю ошибку **IndexError: list index out of range**.

Код:

```
x_i_list = [(0.1*np.pi*i) for i in range(0, 11)] 

order = 3
point_elem_i = 2 # можно взять любое значение: ошибка останется
num=len(x_i_list)

# cтроим конечные разности 
if order < len(y_i_list):
    result_1 = [ np.diff(y_i_list, n=d) for d in np.arange(1, len(y_i_list)) ] 
else:
    print(f'Определите порядок полинома меньше {len(y_i_list)}')

# сгенерируем строки с дельтами 
string_all = [list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, el)) for el in zip_longest(*result_1)]

string_one_1= []
for elen in string_all:
    # если остаток в окне меньше заданного порядка order: 
    if num-point_elem_i <= order:
        # используем вторую строку разностей 
        string_one_1.append(elen[1])
    else:
        string_one_1.append(elen[point_elem_i])
```

Здесь если я убираю условие `else`, то ошибки нет. Интересно, что если я оставляю строку `string_one_1.append(elen[point_elem_i])`, придав переменной `point_elem_i` значение 1, убрав условие `if` с `elen[1]`, то и тогда - ошибка.

Comment: Вы пользуетесь какой-нибудь IDE? Если нет, то просто сделайте print(string_all) перед циклом

Comment: @MBo, я кодирую в Jupyther Notebook.
Если ставить распечатку, получаю вывод переменной `string_all` и ту же ошибку за ним

Comment: Вывод этой переменной - для того, чтобы вы его прочитали и осознали

Comment: @Mbo, я распечатал иначе: `print(string_all[0])`. В итоге -да, получил не ожидавшийся мною вывод. В результате работы данной инструкции мне необходимо извлечь первый из вложенных списков, а я вижу на выводе - весь список списков. Немного не понял, отчего так выходит

Comment: При этом ведь вывод длины `print(len(string_all))` дает корректное значение 10. То количество значений питон видит как 10, но извлечь их по одному не желает

Comment: добавьте перед `string_one_1.append(elen[point_elem_i])`  `print(elen, point_elem_i)`. думаю, так все быстро станет на свои места

Comment: @Alex Kazantsev  Ну и зачем вам длина string_all, если проблема с элементами этого списка. Вот на элементы и посмотрите. На все элементы.

Comment: @MBo, в итоге что-то сделал, поместив свой обновленный код в ответ ниже. Спасибо

Comment: @n1tr0xs, благодаря Вашему совету с разнесением разных элементов, написал новый скрипт, который приложил в ответе на свой вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря комментариям, удалось найти ошибку. Исправил код так, чтобы он пробегал не по элементам вложенных списков, а а по самим этим спискам. В итоге скрипт получилось "отремонтировать".

Код:

```
# приведу только сам исправленный цикл

string_one_1= []

for elen in range(len(string_all)):
    # если остаток в окне меньше заданного порядка order: 
    if num - point_elem_i <= order:
        # используем вторую строку разностей 
        string_one_1.append(string_all[1])
        break
    else:
        string_one_1.append(string_all[point_elem_i])
        break
```